# Problems with Bridged Network Adapter in VirtualBox 6.1

Tags: virtualbox, centos-8, bridged

*I have tried other questions & answers in Stackoverflow, but none of the answers worked for me and also the answers were for older version of VirtualBox or for different OS Hosts. So i'm raising almost a similar question, i don't have a choice.*

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60229370/how-do-i-fix-virtualbox-bridged-adapter-problem

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546719/virtualbox-bridged-interface-wont-connect-to-internet?rq=1

I have a HP Laptop, with 8 GB of RAM(i'm planning to add more RAM) and have CentOS 8 installed.

```
[mani@mani ~]$ uname -a
Linux mani 4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 10 11:09:32 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[mani@mani ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core)
```

I have installed Oracle Virtualbox - Version 6.1.10 r138449 (Qt5.12.5).

My Laptop is connected to WiFi and i can see network adapters created by Virtualbox.

```
virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:f7:11:5b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0-nic: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:f7:11:5b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.114  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::a6d7:3504:aa66:8326  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 4c:34:88:d8:f2:c5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 161355  bytes 191140722 (182.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 57745  bytes 10808240 (10.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have setup few Virtual Machines in the Virtualbox and i'm trying to get them to join my Local Network using the Bridged Network adapter. I want the VMs to be in the same ip range of my Physical Machines.

192.168.0.1 - This is my IP of the router and  my Physical Devices are using 192.168.0[2-254].

I'm trying to get the Virtual Machines

```
a) Lease IPs in the range of 192.168.0[2-254]
b) Reachable from other Virtual Machines as well as Physical machines in my network using the Leased IPs
```

[image]

As you can see i've used Bridged Adapter, but still my VM is not connecting to Internet, neither to my Local Network and definitely not leasing the IPs of my Local Network IP range.

Reference : https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged

My Guest OS VM - CentOS 8 Minimal,

[image]

How do i get this fixed ... Thanks in advance for your help with this.